# Erro Android Studio "Unable to locate adb"

Tags: android-studio

Estou com um erro na hora de executar algum app com o Android Studio. Ele da um erro e retorna essa mensagem:

> Unable to locate adb

Já reinstalei o programa pra voltar pra configuração de fábrica e não resolveu. Se alguém souber da solução agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Acesse o menu `Tools` > `Android` > `SDK Manager`, e então acesse a aba `SDK Tools` e verifique se `Android SDK Platform-Tools` encontra-se instalado (não tenho certeza se estou com a última versão do Android Studio, então o caminho do menu pode variar).

Comment: Sim está instalado. `Android SDK Platform-Tools 24.0.1`